# Expressjs 405 POST method not allowed

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

Route perfectly works well from POSTMAN chrome extension, with Angular it doesn't.

Well here goes my **Express js code** :

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var routes = require('./routes');
var connection  = require('express-myconnection');

app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // for parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded

/** Serve our app on root path */
app.use('/', express.static('app'));

/** Login API */
app.post('/login', routes.login);
```

And here goes **Angular code**:

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: apiUrl + 'login',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' // necessary for expressjs
    },
    transformRequest: function(obj) {
        var str = [];
        for (var p in obj) {
            str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
        }
        return str.join("&");
    },
    data: user
});
```

Not sure whats wrong! This is what I get :

[image]

Comment: What does `routes.login` do?

Comment: it sends user details from database,

Comment: right... but where's the code for it. It clearly isn't returning what you expect it to.

Comment: i dont think thats necessary here!

Comment: What is the value of `apiUrl` in your angular code?...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try inspecting the headers and content for both requests, there's bound to be a difference between the two.  Your response's `Allow` header clearly does not include POST, so there might be some CORS issue going on there.